# How to change the topic name for publishing occupancy grid using map_server?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-saver, occupancy-grid, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Intent : Using mapstitch_hector to get the position of the bot as well as stitching maps.

Problem : Two sets of data are required for mapstitch_hector - /world and /align - in OccupancyGrid format

Data in hand : two sets of .pgm and .yaml files for /world and /align. Acquired via map_saver

Current target : wanted to publish the OccupancyGrids using map_server by the topic /world and /align.

Question : How can I modify the topic for map_server publish? or are there any better idea?

Thank you viewers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227776/how-to-change-the-topic-name-for-publishing-occupancy-grid-using-map_server?/) by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) the `map` and `map_metadata` topics from [`map_server`](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) to what you need, i.e. to `world` and `world_metadata`.

Depending on whether you are using `roslaunch` or `rosrun`, there are different ways.
Use the [`<remap ...>` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) for roslaunch.
If you use rosrun, add the following:
`rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml /map:=/world /map_metadata:=/world_metadata`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on 2016-02-29**:
Thanks! Just what I need!